# Retrofit 1.x - Proguard is Mangling My Custom Annotations

Tags: android, retrofit, proguard

I have a retrofit service defined as such:

```
package com.example.android;

import java.util.Map;

import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

import retrofit.http.RestMethod;

import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.METHOD;
import static java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME;

interface MyRetrofitService {
    @Target(METHOD)
    @Retention(RUNTIME)
    @RestMethod(value = "DELETE", hasBody = true)
    @interface DELETE_WITH_A_BODY {
        String value();
    }   

    @DELETE_WITH_A_BODY(BASE_URL + "/user/{uid}")
    Observable<Result> deleteUser(@Path("uid") String uid, @Body Map<String, String> deleteBody)
}
```

What do I have to tell proguard to make it stop stripping this annotation from the interface method? It's causing problems:

```
03-20 17:04:27.991 21813-27757/? E/RetrofitErrorHandler: 1686168:[ERROR] ~20734 Message: Error happened. Response null., cause MyRetrofitService.deleteUser: HTTP method annotation is required (e.g., @GET, @POST, etc.).
```

I found [an issue on Github](https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/1167), but I can't figure out what the actual proguard rules to make this work are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not specify which rules you already include into your project, but you will need to keep all the RuntimeVisible*Annotation* attributes like that:

```
-keepattributes RuntimeVisible*Annotation*
```

apart from the other attributes that you want to keep.

Edit: also you might need to prevent the annotation classes from being shrunk like this:

```
-keep @interface com.example.android.MyRetrofitService$*
```

This will prevent that annotations that are defined as inner classes in the MyRetrofitService are being shrunk/obfuscated by ProGuard.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following lines to prevent annotation being removed

```
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keepclassmembers interface com.example.android.MyRetrofitService {
    @com.example.android.MyRetrofitService.DELETE_WITH_A_BODY <methods>;
}
```

Comment: This will keep methods that are annotated with this annotation, but the OP asked to keep the annotation itself.

Comment: Hmm... yeah.. I use proguard a lot with eventbus, check the link for eventbus progurard config [here](http://greenrobot.org/eventbus/documentation/proguard/). Its not specifically omitting @Subscribe annotation